# Unable to push git commits

Tags: github

I am trying to push commits to my github repository.

Running `git push -ff` while using HTTPS will give me:
(I am using the `-ff` flag because I was fixing an invalid commit)

```
C:\Users\mooman\Dropbox\Project\Workspace\MilkBukkit [master]> git push -ff
Counting objects: 28390, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7515/7515), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28390/28390), 4.28 MiB, done.
Total 28390 (delta 13498), reused 28182 (delta 13449)
efrror: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0
atal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: recursion detected in die handler
Everything up-to-date
```

I already ran `git gc` and `git fsck`, but the problem persists.

Using HTTP used to hang at around 10%, but I adjusted the buffer using `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000` where it now produce the results as shown above.

Attempted using SSH by running: `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/mooman219/CowCode.git` which results in:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,204.232.175.90' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Counting objects: 28390, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7515/7515), done.
Writing objects: 27% (28390/28390)
```

But it hangs after there.

I also tried port forwarding the git protocol `port 9418` and disabling any firewall I have but the results are the same for both SSH and HTTP.

Comment: Any reason for the `-ff` flag? `-f` is a valid flag, but unless you already know you need to use it in this case, I wouldn't recommend it normally... I doubt that's the issue, just curious.

Comment: I need to use the -ff flag because my local branch is behind the remote one because I needed to fix an invalid commit.

Comment: Just checking that you did intend to force. `-f` should be sufficient, though `-ff` should accomplish the same. `git merge` has an `-ff` flag which is very different from `git push`'s `-f` flag, hence my question & confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GitHub](http://github.com) appears to be down right now (you can check at https://status.github.com/ to see when they come back).  Try again after they've finished fighting off whatever interstellar space bugs have stricken them.

Answer (score 3):

According to http://status.github.com/ -
[image]
They are "experiencing technical difficulties"